# Map navigation - Titanium

Tags: titanium, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I implement navigation in map in my application? When I click on a navigation button, it should navigate to the destination when the user starts moving. I researched on google. I didn't get any solution. Please some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to open the device google map instead of ti.map

```
var directionUrl;
directionUrl = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=" + dirLatitude + "," + dirLongitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
```

This is working fine for me.